# Netbeans 7.0 compiler error

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, compiler-errors

I am using Netbeans 7.0 and get this error when I try to compile, and debug:

```
    make: *** [.validate-impl] Error 127

    BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 281ms)
```

I set my environment variables (within Windows) to C:\cygwin\bin
Within Netbeans my build tools are of the Cygwin family. The C compiler is Gcc, C++ compiler is G++, Assembler is as.exe, make command is make.exe, and debugger is gdb.exe. They're all located within C:\cygwin\bin\FILENAMEHERE

And finally, my source code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers:" << std::endl;
    int v1, v2;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 "and " << v2 << "is" << v1 +v2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you build from the command line?

Comment: I don't know how to compile via a command line, or how to access the command line, unless it is terminal. So if you can tell me what to write in the command line, then I will try. :)

Comment: Its not a terminal, but I guess that's what you are thinking of it as. You should really learn how to use it. And I'd really suggest using something other than cgwin & netbeans, such as VC++ Express or Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a LOT of problems with the 7.0 C++ version. It keeps destroying the auto generated make files. I removed it and downgraded. The 6.9.1 version is still available and seems to work much better.

p.s.

If you're going to be doing QT development it matters which compiler chain you choose. You want to look for "mingw tdm dw2". The SJLJ version of mingw (which is the default) does not work with the released QT binary libraries.